# Extract data from NSMutableData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

How can I extract the data from a `NSMutabledata` structure which returned by `NSConection`, like this:

```
<response>
TOKEN=abcdef
</response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question is tagged iPhone i think you mean `NSURLConnection` and not `NSConnection`. My answer is based on that assumption.

You will have to implement the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods and get all the data into an NSMutableData object. I hope you have already done this as you have the `NSMutableData`.

How to get data in the format you want depends on what type of data is being returned by the connection. If its an XML or JSON you will have to use a parser. [An XML parser](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is available in objective c. If it is a sipmle string, you can directly convert it to a string in your `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method and use it:

```
NSString *receivedDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedMutableData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```